# OnActivityResult given null data from intent

Tags: android, kotlin, image-gallery, onactivityresult

Im getting problem when I get image from gallery and put intent data as null. I have same code in other fragment where I register a user with foto and there is no problem there.
[This is profilefragment where the error happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ti3Hq.png)

```
private fun loadImage() {
    /*val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    startActivityForResult(intent, pickImage)*/
    val imageIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
    startActivityForResult(imageIntent, pickImage) //funciona*/

}
@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (resultCode == AppCompatActivity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == pickImage) {

        if (data != null) {
            try {
                val imageUri = data.data //data.extras!!.get("data") as Bitmap
                val bitmap =
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context?.contentResolver, imageUri)
                avatar.setImageURI(imageUri)
                register_avatarFilename.setText("image_test")
                register_avatarFiledata.text = saveImage(bitmap)
            } catch (ioe: IOException) {
                ioe.printStackTrace()
                register_avatarFilename.setText("Image upload failed")
            }
        }
    }
}

fun saveImage(myBitmap: Bitmap): String {
    val bytes = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes)
    val b = bytes.toByteArray()
    val encodedAvatar = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT)
    return encodedAvatar
}
```

Comment: please post your code here, as text, not as an image and provide enough to recreate the problem

Comment: Sorry for late response, this is the code. I have same code where I register a user with his photo, but it doesn't work on profile where user can update his profile if he wants. I tried debug but the intent return null data after user select the pic.

Answer (score -1):

```
Put this code In Activity One

Intent intent = getIntent();
intent.putExtra("Date",dateSelected);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();


And this code on second activity 

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode==1) {
        Bundle MBuddle = data.getExtras();
        String MMessage = MBuddle.getString("Date");
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but this is not what im looking for. I dont want to pass a bundle to seconde activity, these are diffrent fragments and in 1 fragment the above code works well and in second one return null data.